# How to make a NSWindow act like a Social Network Sharing Sheet?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

So, here's what a default sharing sheet looks like:
[image]
As you can see, the sharing sheet will appear on top of the window, and dim whats behind it. How can I make a `NSWindow` act like that (dim what's behind and make everything unselectable)? I've been searching but I can't find the answer.
Thanks!

Comment: [NSApp runModalForWindow:MyWindow.window];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new NSView (derive your own class to be able to implement drawRect:) and make it semi transparent. Put it over all your other views in the window. This will prevent mouse events to reach other views and achieve the dimmed look. Then use a modal window for the "social sheet".